# HEVC vs H264 video file size

Tags: encoding, codec, h.264, h265, hevc

I am doing some experiments on the file size of recorded videos in `HEVC` vs the ones recorded in `H264` using a simple Android app that I developed. My impression was that videos recorded in HEVC should generally have **almost half size** (or at least much lower size) compared to ones recorded in H264 given they have same duration and almost same contents (I capture the same scene with phone's camera). But when I compare their metadata using `mediaInfo`, it is not really like. I wonder why.

What is going on here? Am I missing anything?! What should I do to prove this concept?

Here is what I set:

```
    mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
    mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
    //choose HEVC or H264
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(5000 * 1000);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(30);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(1280, 720);
```

Here is the mediaInfo for the `HEVC` video:

```
General 
Complete name : VID_20211225_210352.mp4 
Format : MPEG-4 
Format profile : Base Media / Version 2 
Codec ID : mp42 (isom/mp42) 
File size : 763 KiB 
Duration : 1 s 447 ms 
Overall bit rate : 4 322 kb/s 
Encoded date : UTC 2021-12-25 17:33:56 
Tagged date : UTC 2021-12-25 17:33:56 
com.android.version : 11 

Video 
ID : 1 
Format : HEVC 
Format/Info : High Efficiency Video Coding 
Format profile : Main@L3.1@Main 
Codec ID : hvc1 
Codec ID/Info : High Efficiency Video Coding 
Duration : 1 s 447 ms 
Source duration : 1 s 441 ms 
Bit rate : 4 316 kb/s 
Width : 1 280 pixels 
Height : 720 pixels 
Display aspect ratio : 16:9 
Frame rate mode : Variable 
Frame rate : 29.837 FPS 
Minimum frame rate : 23.112 FPS 
Maximum frame rate : 30.050 FPS 
Standard : PAL 
Color space : YUV 
Chroma subsampling : 4:2:0 
Bit depth : 8 bits 
Bits/(Pixel*Frame) : 0.157 
Stream size : 759 KiB (99%) 
Source stream size : 759 KiB (99%) 
Title : VideoHandle 
Language : English 
Encoded date : UTC 2021-12-25 17:33:56 
Tagged date : UTC 2021-12-25 17:33:56 
Color range : Limited 
Color primaries : BT.709 
Transfer characteristics : BT.709 
Matrix coefficients : BT.709 
mdhd_Duration : 1447 
Codec configuration box : hvcC 

Audio 
ID : 2 
Format : AAC LC 
Format/Info : Advanced Audio Codec Low Complexity 
Codec ID : mp4a-40-2 
Duration : 1 s 408 ms 
Bit rate mode : Constant 
Bit rate : 13.1 kb/s 
Nominal bit rate : 12.2 kb/s 
Channel(s) : 1 channel 
Channel layout : C 
Sampling rate : 8 000 Hz 
Frame rate : 7.812 FPS (1024 SPF) 
Compression mode : Lossy 
Stream size : 2.26 KiB (0%) 
Title : SoundHandle 
Language : English 
Encoded date : UTC 2021-12-25 17:33:56 
Tagged date : UTC 2021-12-25 17:33:56
```

And here is the mediaInfo for the H264 video:

```
General 
Complete name : VID_20211225_210425.mp4 
Format : MPEG-4 
Format profile : Base Media / Version 2 
Codec ID : mp42 (isom/mp42) 
File size : 719 KiB 
Duration : 1 s 409 ms 
Overall bit rate : 4 178 kb/s 
Encoded date : UTC 2021-12-25 17:34:28 
Tagged date : UTC 2021-12-25 17:34:28 
com.android.version : 11 

Video 
ID : 1 
Format : AVC 
Format/Info : Advanced Video Codec 
Format profile : High@L3.1 
Format settings : CABAC / 1 Ref Frames 
Format settings, CABAC : Yes 
Format settings, Reference frames : 1 frame 
Codec ID : avc1 
Codec ID/Info : Advanced Video Coding 
Duration : 1 s 408 ms 
Bit rate : 4 157 kb/s 
Width : 1 280 pixels 
Height : 720 pixels 
Display aspect ratio : 16:9 
Frame rate mode : Variable 
Frame rate : 29.832 FPS 
Minimum frame rate : 23.107 FPS 
Maximum frame rate : 30.050 FPS 
Standard : PAL 
Color space : YUV 
Chroma subsampling : 4:2:0 
Bit depth : 8 bits 
Scan type : Progressive 
Bits/(Pixel*Frame) : 0.151 
Stream size : 714 KiB (99%) 
Title : VideoHandle 
Language : English 
Encoded date : UTC 2021-12-25 17:34:28 
Tagged date : UTC 2021-12-25 17:34:28 
Color range : Limited 
Color primaries : BT.709 
Transfer characteristics : BT.709 
Matrix coefficients : BT.709 
mdhd_Duration : 1408 
Codec configuration box : avcC 

Audio 
ID : 2 
Format : AAC LC 
Format/Info : Advanced Audio Codec Low Complexity 
Codec ID : mp4a-40-2 
Duration : 1 s 409 ms 
Source duration : 1 s 408 ms 
Bit rate mode : Constant 
Bit rate : 13.4 kb/s 
Nominal bit rate : 12.2 kb/s 
Channel(s) : 1 channel 
Channel layout : C 
Sampling rate : 8 000 Hz 
Frame rate : 7.812 FPS (1024 SPF) 
Compression mode : Lossy 
Stream size : 2.31 KiB (0%) 
Source stream size : 2.31 KiB (0%) 
Title : SoundHandle 
Language : English 
Encoded date : UTC 2021-12-25 17:34:28 
Tagged date : UTC 2021-12-25 17:34:28 
mdhd_Duration : 1409
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've specified the encoding bit rate to be `5000*1000` kbs. So the constraint here is the file size, not the quality of the video (i.e., all of your videos will be approximately `5 kbs * duration` in size, regardless of the choice of encoding).

HEVC has the potential to have higher quality at a given bit rate, though it comes at a cost of encoding speed (i.e., better compression also takes more time; for certain levels of compute, the difference between x264 and HEVC might be de minimus).

See also [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1557090/294360).

Comment: Ok..So if I make the hevc bitrate half, what should be the acceptable psnr? So if too off, I increase the hevc bitrate more than half.

Comment: If you're comparing x264/HEVC to the uncompressed original, you should be able to get the same PSNR using a lower bitrate with HEVC. You might have to fiddle with some of the encoding settings and you might decide to have a slightly higher HEVC bitrate than half of an acceptable x264 bitrate to achieve the same quality.